# How to provide gift card code automatically to user who likes product on the magento based ecommerce site

Tags: magento

Is there any way to link face-book like feature with the magento gift card code. Like if any user/visitor likes any product on the site then store administrator want to sent gift code automatically to that user. This should happen automatically without involvement of any manual process.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Rather than sending a gift card code, you should generate a one time use coupon code and send them that.

In terms of tracking the Facebook like, you can use Facebook's FB.Event.subscribe method which is a part of their JavaScript SDK. A simple snippet will allow you to listen for a "like" event, the SDK will then provide you with a callback containing the URL liked (the current page). You can pretty much do whatever you want from there.

Everything you need should be here: [Facebook JS SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)